# Multipart File Upload using AngularJS and SpringMVC

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring-mvc

I am new to angularJS and trying to upload a file using angular JS and Spring MVC, but not able to get the required solution and ending up with exceptions in JS Controller.

Below is the code, Have a look and please help me out. Thank you

**ApplicationContext.xml**

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000" /> <!-- setting maximum upload size -->
</bean>
```

**JSP:**

```
<div data-ng-controller='QuestionController'>
<form name="createChapForm" data-ng-submit="submitQue();" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Select Class * :</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <select data-ng-model='class_id' data-ng-init='getClasses();' data-ng-change='getSubjectsClasswise(class_id);' class="form-control" required>
                    <option value="">--SELECT--</option>
                    <option data-ng-repeat='c in clss' value="{{ c.class_id}}">{{ c.class_name}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Select Subject * :</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <select data-ng-model='question.sid' data-ng-change='doGetChapters(question.sid);' class="form-control" required>
                    <option value="">--SELECT--</option>
                    <option data-ng-repeat='s in subsss' value="{{ s.sid}}">{{ s.subject_name}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Select Chapter :</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <select data-ng-model='question.chap_id' class="form-control" >
                    <option value="">ALL</option>
                    <option data-ng-repeat='c in chapters' value="{{ c.chap_id}}">{{ c.chap_name}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2" >Question :</div>
        <div class="col-sm-10 padding_0">
            <textarea data-ng-model='question.question_text' rows="5" class="form-control  " > </textarea>
            <div class="right">
                <div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary1 btn-sm">
                    <input type="file" data-ng-model="file" name="file" id="file"  id="q_id"  class="upload" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

**AngularJS Controller:**

```
$scope.submitQue = function() {
    console.log('file is ' ); console.dir(file.files[0]);
    var URL =appURL+'/adm/doAddQuestion.do';
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', file.files[0]);
    fd.append('questionBean', angular.toJson($scope.question, true));
    $http.post(URL, fd, {
        transformRequest : angular.identity,
        headers : {
            'Content-Type' : undefined
        }
    }).success(function() {
        console.log('success');
    }).error(function() {
        console.log('error');
    });
}
```

**Java Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/doAddQuestion.do", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody String saveUserDataAndFile(@RequestParam(value = "file") MultipartFile file, @RequestBody QuestionBean questionBean) {
    System.out.println("output: "+questionBean.getQuestion_text());
    // Im Still wotking on it
    return "";
}
```

**Exceptions:**

```
Mar 08, 2017 7:46:46 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver handleHttpMessageNotReadable
WARNING: Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Unexpected character ('-' (code 45)) in numeric value: expected digit (0-9) to follow minus sign, for valid numeric value
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@bc03e1; line: 1, column: 3]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('-' (code 45)) in numeric value: expected digit (0-9) to follow minus sign, for valid numeric value
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@bc03e1; line: 1, column: 3]
Mar 08, 2017 7:46:46 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver logException
WARNING: Handler execution resulted in exception: Could not read document: Unexpected character ('-' (code 45)) in numeric value: expected digit (0-9) to follow minus sign, for valid numeric value
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@bc03e1; line: 1, column: 3]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('-' (code 45)) in numeric value: expected digit (0-9) to follow minus sign, for valid numeric value
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@bc03e1; line: 1, column: 3]
```

Comment: Your error is clear `Expected MultipartHttpServletRequest: is a MultipartResolver configured?` @see [Multipart Resolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartResolver.html)

Comment: @EddieB changed but still giving the same exception

Comment: 'Changed' `?` You need to `configure a multipart resolver`... @more info [Configure Multipart Resolver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23570014/spring-4-java-config-for-multipartresolver-for-servlet-3-0)

Comment: @EddieB updated the changes, please have a look

Comment: Your original issue. `multipart resolver` is resolved. You need to follow the SO rules and post a new question for the `new problem`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add these `.js` file where you have added `angular.js` files `angular-file-upload.js`,`angular-file-upload-shim.js`,`ng-file-upload.js`,`ng-file-upload-shim.js`

You can download from this link [Angular File For Upload.](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ourdwyey22mlipy/AABJme1IC1ZXO4zzoZZTHmTPa?dl=0)

Then Add `ngFileUpload,'angularFileUpload'` in `angular.module` see below line.

```
angular.module('formSubmit', [ 'ngFileUpload',
            'angularFileUpload',  'ui.router' ]);
```

Then Add `$upload` in your angular controller like this.

```
app.controller('FormSubmitController', function($scope, $http, $upload)
```

Use `$upload.upload` instead of `$http.post` in your angular code.

```
$upload.upload({
    url : 'doAddQuestion.do',
    file : yourFile,
    data : $scope.questionBean,
    method : 'POST'
});
```

Change your spring controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/doAddQuestion.do", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = ("content-type=multipart/*"))
public @ResponseBody String saveUserDataAndFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, QuestionBean questionBean) {
    System.out.println("output: "+questionBean.getQuestion_text());
            // Im Still wotking on it
    return "";
}
```

Comment: what is this `yourFile`?

Comment: In your case you have to replace with this code `file.files[0]`

Comment: showing error in console `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $uploadProvider <- $upload`

Comment: I have edited my answer please follow all the steps.

Comment: I used the exact files and suggested controller parameter list. I am getting a
`400 (Bad Request)`
Any suggestions why that is?

Answer (score 0):

**update your request mapping with the following code:**

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/upload-file", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
```

It will remove your multipart exception.

Comment: changed but still giving the same exception

Comment: I think your multipart exception is been resolved now, the current issue is might be in your request object now.

Comment: no.. now its giving some different exception.. i updated the question, have a look

Comment: "QuestionBean" is your entity class? if yes then implements Serializable, as suugested in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34888326/spring-is-giving-httpmessagenotreadableexception-to-ajax-post. Let me know if it works for you

Comment: @hrdkisback - I am trying the same exact functionality you mentioned above in answer..Even i'm facing the error. It is showing error in console Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $uploadProvider <- $upload..i followed all the steps you metioned in the answer..Any inputs?