# Spring boot and Angularjs Multipartfile and application/xml

Tags: java, angularjs, xml, spring-boot, multipartform-data

It's my controller in spring boot

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "multipart/form-data")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<?> test(
            @RequestParam("enveloppe") Enveloppe enveloppe,
            @RequestParam("files") MultipartFile[] uploadFiles) {


    }
```

It's my service in angularJs

```
var fd = new FormData();
    angular.forEach(files, function(file) {
        fd.append('files', file);
    })
    fd.append('enveloppe', enveloppe, {type :'application/xml'} );
    $http.post("/test", fd, {
        transformRequest : angular.identity,
        headers : {
            'Content-Type' : undefined
        }
```

My object "enveloppe"  generated automatically by xsd in spring boot.
my object "enveloppe" in angularjs converted by json2Xml lib  to have xml.
But, spring boot cant' wrapper the object enveloppe. ~

1 ) it's possible to do that ?

Comment: This link might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42671510/multipart-file-upload-using-angularjs-and-springmvc/42717177#42717177

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution with spring boot and xml for the second part with @RequestPart

My controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "multipart/form-data")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<?> test(
            @RequestPart("enveloppe") Enveloppe enveloppe,
            @RequestPart("files") MultipartFile[] uploadFiles) {


    }
```

angularjs service

```
var fd = new FormData();
        angular.forEach(files, function(file) {
            fd.append('files', file);
        })
        fd.append('enveloppe', new Blob([enveloppe], {type: 'application/xml'}));

        $http.post("/test", fd, {
            transformRequest : angular.identity,
            headers : {
                'Content-Type' : undefined
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible but instead appending in formData in service, i would say do it in controller

```
<input type="file" id="filename">
```

In your controller

```
var file=document.getElementById("filename").files[0];
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("fileKey", file);
```

then send data to backend using your service.

Comment: I have technical constraint, I have list of file, I can to send 6 files together.