# Angular Spring Boot File Upload

Tags: angular, spring-boot, file-upload, multipart

I need to write an upload angular module that uses spring boot controller and multipart file. But when I am uploading the file i have an error

```
Current request is not a multipart request
```

I tried alot of changes but every time I get this error. Here is my angular file sender data service

```
    function uploadFile (file) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', file);

        $http({
            data : fd,
            method: 'POST',
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            url: "/api/private/upload",
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        }).then(function (response) {
            deferred.resolve(response.data);
        }, function (response) {
            deferred.reject(response.message);
        }).catch(function (response) {
            deferred.reject(response.message);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

And here is my Controller 
 `public String singleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        return "redirect:/uploadStatus";
    }`

It is not working with or without multipart Resolver. Can you please help me with this file upload.

Comment: This link might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42671510/multipart-file-upload-using-angularjs-and-springmvc/42717177#42717177

Answer (score 0):

ArrayBuffer to blob conversion is all you need inside your `uploadFile` function. See a sample [here](https://github.com/alextunyk/fileupload-metadata/blob/b7e0f8e251f82c203486894ea45ec9d0b041f878/web/src/App.js#L46)

```
  let fileReader = new FileReader();

  fileReader.onloadend = (e) => {
    let arrayBuffer = e.target.result;
    let data = arrayBufferToBlob(arrayBuffer, file.type);

    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', data);

    // do $http request here
  };

  fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(yourFileFromInputElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

IN HTML

```
<input type="file" name="myfile" (change)="selectFile($event)" 
accept=".png" placeholder="Upload Image" required/>
```

**IN component TS**

```
/* File Upload request  to Upload file  */
    this.currentFileUpload = this.selectedFiles.item(0);
    let formdata: FormData = new FormData();
    formdata.append('file', this.currentFileUpload);
    this.shareServices.FileUpload(this.currentFileUpload, path, this.imageName)
      .subscribe(data => {

      })
```

**this For Service TS**

```
public FileUpload(editObj: File, id, getNewFileName) {
    let formdata: FormData = new FormData();
    formdata.append('file', editObj);
    return this.httpClient.post(this.Core_URL + '/submitTask/' + id + "/" + getNewFileName, formdata)


  }
```

**This All for  file Upload**