# Sending mail with attachment - angularJS + Java Spring

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, email

I've got working email sender, but without attachments. I tried something like this:

Simple input in HTML:

```
<input type="file" simple-change="uploadFiles($event)"/>
```

JS file picker:

```
    $scope.uploadFiles = function (event) {
    $scope.file= event.target.files[0];
};
```

And JS email sender:

```
$scope.sendEmail = function(){
    $scope.emailData = new EmailData();
    $scope.emailData.to = "example@gmail.com";
    $scope.emailData.from = "boss@gmail.com";
    $scope.emailData.subject = "Errors";
    $scope.emailData.title = $scope.topic;
    $scope.emailData.description = $scope.description;
    $scope.emailData.template = "templateErrors";

    $http.post("sendemail/attachment", $scope.emailData, $scope.file, {headers: {'Content-Type': undefined} })
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.succes =  true;
    },
    function(fail) {
        $scope.error = true;
    });
}
```

Java Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/attachment", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public EmailStatus sendEmailAttach(@RequestBody EmailData emailData, CommonsMultipartFile file) {
    return emailSenderAttachment.sendDataAttach(emailData, file);
}
```

but still got error 500:  ""message":"org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileUploadException""

Please help :(

Comment: What is the full stacktrace of the exception ?

Comment: Umm im not sure.. ure talkking about full error ({"timestamp":"2017-12-21T15:49:20.888+0000","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError","message":"org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileUploadException","path":"/sendemail/zalacznik"}) or just about full of Java code?

Comment: Umm i added dependency, which I missed to add CommonsMultipartFile. But who know why I've got null in file object (java side)? Code same as above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code use `$upload.upload` instead of `$http.post` for upload file to server.

**AngularJs**

```
$upload.upload({
    method : 'POST',
    url : 'sendemail/attachment',
    file : $scope.file,
    data : $scope.emailData
}).success(function(response) {
    console.log("Success");
}).error(function(error) {
    console.log("Error");
});
```

**Spring Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/attachment", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public EmailStatus sendEmailAttach(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, EmailData emailData) {
    return emailSenderAttachment.sendDataAttach(emailData, file);
}
```

For more details you can refer my answer from this post [Multipart File Upload using AngularJS and SpringMVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42671510/multipart-file-upload-using-angularjs-and-springmvc/42717177#42717177)

Comment: I've got still error like: "message":"Required request part 'file' is not present"

Comment: Try this `@RequestMapping(value = "/attachment", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = ("content-type=multipart/*"))` add `headers`.

Comment: glad to hear this :)